# using dynamic link in tailwlind classes nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

say I have something like this in nextjs, when I run it I get the error

'Module not found: Can't resolve './${game.image}'

```
const Categories = () => {
   const Games = 
   [
    {
      name: "World of warcraft",
      image: "/assets/wow.png",
    },
    {
      name: "League of Legends",
      image: "/assets/lol.png",
    }
   ]

   return (
     <div>
     {Games.map((game, index) => (
       <div key={index} className={`flex w-full h-full bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('${game.image}')]`}>
       </div>
      ))}
     </div>
   )}

export default Categories
```

how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
const Games = 
    [
      name: "World of warcraft",
      image: "/assets/wow.png",
    ],
    [
      name: "League of Legends",
      image: "/assets/lol.png",
    ]
```

Should be:

```
const Games = 
    [{
      name: "World of warcraft",
      image: "/assets/wow.png",
    },
    {
      name: "League of Legends",
      image: "/assets/lol.png",
  }]
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, that is how I have wrote it in the site, I wrote it by mistake in the question and its now edited. that is not the issue.

Comment: So I guess that this line `<div key={index} className={`flex w-full h-full bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('${game.image}')]`}>` is also different

Comment: no, should it be ? that is how I assumed it should be

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to make the object items themselves the class

so for example:

```
const Games = [
  {
    name: "World of warcraft",
    image: "bg-[url('/assets/wow.png')]",
  }
]
```

and then just use the ${image} as a class name.